# Is it possible to create a dynamic RecyclerView Adapter that accepts List of any Object List<Object>?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Case 1:
Show list of `productName` in `View` while sending `List<Products> productList` in adapter constructor.

Case 2:
Show list of `categoryName` in `View` while sending `List<Category> categoryList` in adapter constructor.

Both the cases must use the same `RecyclerView` Adapter.

The adapter may have `List<Object> objectList`. But how can show different property of the different object in the `View`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

Comment: I wanted something different. Probably you didn't understood. @OnurD.

Comment: I think I understood correctly. As you said, you can keep a list of Objects in your adapter while having multiple ViewHolders in it. A ProductViewHolder for a Product, a CategoryViewHolder for a Category object etc. After this, it all comes to putting if-else or switch-case conditions on your `getItemViewType()` method as well as `onCreateViewHolder()`

Comment: Not multiple view holder actually. I just wanted to use the same `viewHolder` for different `List` of Objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the type:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(WhateverHolder holder, int position) {
    Object item = itemsList.get(position);

    if (item instanceof Products) {
        Product product = (Product) item;
        //populate the ViewHolder with the information
    } else if (item instanceof Category) {
        Category category = (Category) item;
        //populate the ViewHolder
    } else {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid item: " + item.getClass().getCanonicalName()); //this is optional 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @TheWanderer. Your solution worked. I wanted exactly this type.